# vagrant/multiple instance mysqld

Tags: mysql, vagrant, multiple-instances

So I'm trying to setup a vagrant precise64 box with multiple mysqld instances all listening on separate ports and using separate socket files.

My cnf file is here with what I believe is correct ownership and permissions

```
vagrant@mysqld:~$ sudo ls -la /home/mysql/user.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 3562 Oct 30 13:26 /home/mysql/user.cnf
```

but when I attempt to start my mysqld instance, I get

```
vagrant@mysqld:~$ sudo mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/home/mysql/user.cnf --user=mysql &
[1] 11624
vagrant@mysqld:~$ 151030 16:07:33 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
151030 16:07:33 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
151030 16:07:33 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/dbs/user/mysql/data
151030 16:07:33 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/dbs/user/mysql/mysqld_user.pid ended
```

and if I look at the error.log I see that it complains it cannot open the file.

```
151030 16:07:33 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/dbs/user/mysql/data
Could not open required defaults file: /home/mysql/user.cnf
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
151030 16:07:33 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/dbs/user/mysql/mysqld_user.pid ended
```

anyone have any ideas?  I've burned far too much time on this already.

Here is the contents of my cnf file

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/lib/dbs/user/mysql/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/lib/dbs/user/mysql/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/lib/dbs/user/mysql/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/dbs/user/mysql/data
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql/
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a long shot, but how about trying to open the /home/mysql directory to the world for reading?  `chmod o+x /home/mysql` for a test?

Comment: tried and same thing.  

`vagrant@mysqld:~$ sudo ls -la /home/mysql/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 4096 Oct 30 13:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root  4096 Oct 30 12:17 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql  220 Oct 30 12:17 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 3486 Oct 30 12:17 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql  675 Oct 30 12:17 .profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 3562 Oct 30 13:26 user.cnf
vagrant@mysqld:~$`  

`Could not open required defaults file: /home/mysql/user.cnf`

Comment: Post your .cnf file, I can try it on my Vagrant setup.